# Apache basic authentication not working in Chrome but Firefox and IE/Edge

Tags: apache, .htaccess, google-chrome, cross-browser, .htpasswd

I am not able to access a protected directory in Chrome anymore. I could however access the directory in other browsers (Firefox and IE). 
Why is it not working in Chrome? I don't have a domain name and the the apache configuration has AllowOverride set to "All".

*on Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)*